Improve EF query performance - GroupBy OrderByDescending First
We have the following class and corresponding DB table:
[Index(nameof(ItemId))]
public class DataSnapshot
{
    [Key]
    public long SeqNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedTimestamp { get; set; }
}

Whenever an item's data is changed, a new row is inserted into the table. To retrieve the most recent data for all items, we currently execute the following query:
var latestDataSnapshots = context.DataSnapshots
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedTimestamp).First())
    .ToListAsync();

This query is translated into the following SQL:
SELECT "t0"."SeqNo",
       "t0"."CreatedTimestamp",
       "t0"."ItemId",
       "t0"."Data"
FROM   (SELECT   "e"."ItemId"
        FROM     "DataSnapshots" AS "e"
        GROUP BY "e"."ItemId") AS "t"
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT "t1"."SeqNo",
                         "t1"."CreatedTimestamp",
                         "t1"."ItemId",
                         "t1"."Data"
                  FROM   (SELECT "e0"."SeqNo",
                                 "e0"."CreatedTimestamp",
                                 "e0"."ItemId",
                                 "e0"."Data"
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "e0"."ItemId" ORDER BY "e0"."CreatedTimestamp" DESC) AS "row"
                          FROM   "DataSnapshots" AS "e0") AS "t1"
                  WHERE  "t1"."row" <= 1) AS "t0"
       ON "t"."ItemId" = "t0"."ItemId"

This query works as desired but, unfortunately (but not surprisingly), the query's performance takes a hit as the number of rows in the table increases (sometimes the query even times out).
Can anyone suggest anything that we can do to make this query faster/more efficient? Any and all help appreciated.
We have complete end to end control of both the DB and C# code. We are using .NET 6.0 and latest Entity Framework 6.0.0 packages.

Without third-party extensions you can use only SQL. You should extract subquery with ROW_NUMBER filter - "t0". Other part of SQL should be dropped.

Does DataSnapshot happen to have a parent it refers to? Probably Item.

You created your own temporal tables implementation. EF Core knows how to use them.

It implies you need a compound index: ItemId asc + CreatedTimestamp desc; so you can seek on ItemId and get the "latest" time stamped item for that ItemId.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for your comment but we do not want to get into maintaining SQL queries and would like to use an EF solution.

@GertArnold No, DataSnapshot does not have a "parent" (e.g., Item is not a foreign key).

@Felix, then you have no options. Only SQL can improve this query. Or you can use third party extansions for that.
